# Limit ssh access to only one Repo

Tags: ssh, git, bitbucket

I'm hosting multiple private repositories on bitbucket. 
I also have access to a private repository let's call it repo1, on bitbucket which is not mine but we pull from it on a server, let's call it 
server1.

On bitbucket, I have granted access to my account to server1, which means all users on server1 can pull any repo from my bitbucket account.

How can I prevent this and let only ther server pull the repo1? 
It's kinda urgent. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you added the server1 pubkey to the **team**, instead of to the **repository**. Remove the team-level deploy key and add it to only the repository/repositories they need access to.

Comment: Hi ! Thank you for your answer & time. 
`It sounds like you added their pubkey`. To whom does "their" refer ?
What I did was, generate an ssh key and past it on bitbucket account

Comment: "Their" is the key from server1. I understand you "pasted it on the bitbucket account". The problem is that you pasted it in the wrong location.

Comment: Yes that's what I did. How can I add it to the repo ? 
That's actually what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: In the repo settings, "Deployment Keys" section.